# Appcache no Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, html5, .net

preciso utilizar o appcache do html5 para armazenas algumas páginas web. Antes de utilizar o MVC eu simplesmente fiz essa expressão regular para verificar se está com conexão ou não.

```
var offlinePages = /^\/(index|about|schedule|location).htm$/;
```

E nesse loop eu faço o teste :

```
var hideLinksThatRequireOnline = function () {
    var allNavLinks = document.querySelectorAll("nav.page-nav a");
    for (var i = 0; i < allNavLinks.length; i++) {
        var href = allNavLinks[i].getAttribute("href");
        if (!offlinePages.test(href)) {
            allNavLinks[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
};
```

Até aí tudo bem , só que agora eu vou trabalhar com MVC , vou ter Controlers e Actions, então eu tive que mudar a expressão :

```
var offlinePages = /^\/(Index|About).htm$/;
```

Eu não coloquei Controller/Index , pois quando coloquei a barra , deu erro na expressão regular. Só que não funcionou, alguém tem alguma ideia de como fazer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Em javascript, a barra `/` é reservada para indicar o início ou o fim da expressão regular. Para que sua expressão aceite strings que contenham barras, você precisa utilizar um caracter de escape - que nesse caso seria a barra invertida `\`. No caso, a expressão resultante seria:

```
var offlinePages = /^\/(Controller\/Index|Controller\/About).htm$/;
```

Caso se trate de um único Controller, a expressão pode ser simplificada para:

```
var offlinePages = /^\/Controller\/(Index|About).htm$/;
```

Tenha em mente, porém, que utilizando asp.net mvc, as rotas não são diretamente mapeadas aos arquivos da sua solução, e portanto, não faz sentido associá-las às extensões destes arquivos. No seu caso, basta retirar da expressão o sufixo `.htm`. A expressão final, no caso, seria:

```
var offlinePages = /^\/Controller\/(Index|About)$/;
```

Comment: Obrigadado pela ajuda, eu fiquei com uma outra dúvida , como guardar essas views no arquivo de manifesto , eu fiz :  /home/index
/home/about   , só que não funcionou , eu também tentei colocar views/home/index.cshtml só que também não foi.

Comment: /Home/Index e /Home/About deveria funcionar. Eu sugiro que você crie uma nova questão para este problema, dando mais informacões (por exemplo, como está o restante do seu arquivo de manifesto? como vc o referenciou no html?).